# NSNotification not fired from inside the dispatch async

Tags: ios

I have the following code:

Inside the session completionHandler I have a dispatch_async which contains the call to the NSNotificationCenter post Notification method. But the notification is never fired Any ideas!

```
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];

[[session dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url] completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

    // populating appDelegate.statusItems variable ///// 

   ....... 

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()
                   , ^{

                       [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"DataReceived" object:nil userInfo:@{@"StatusItems":appDelegate.statusItems}];

                        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"DashboardSegue" sender:nil];
                   });



}]resume];
```

Inside the LoginViewController (the code is above) I also register the notifications for the listeners but they are never called:

```
    -(void) setupNotifications
    {
        ViewController *viewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController"];

        [viewController registerNotifications];

    }


-(void) registerNotifications
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(populateList:) name:@"DataReceived" object:nil];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

-(void) populateList:(NSNotification *) notification
{
    NSDictionary *dict = notification.userInfo;

    _statusItems =  [dict valueForKey:@"StatusItems"];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    });

}
```

Comment: Is the registerNotifications method getting called?  Would you have to use [self registerNotifications]  and not [viewController registerNotifications]

Comment: DashboardSegue class receives notification. Maybe notification is sent before this view is create.